How to create procedural ceiling tile Gradient texture?
I'm trying to create a procedural drop ceiling texture, and I have been able to create a simple one, even one with stains/water damage. However, I would like to try add depth to the texture, specifically by overlaying a gradient texture over individual tiles, and having it be randomized in rotation (increments of 90 degrees) and location. Additionally, I'm not using geometry nodes, as the texture is a custom PBR. Does anyone have any suggestions, or at least any advice?

Here's the texture without stains.

Here it is with stains.

There might be many different ways of doing this, but one that matches your tiling would sort of require us to know how you're making the tiles.

There is no geometry to the ceiling tiles, as it's purely a flat texture repeated.

That is not enough... is each tile "one image"? Is it procedural? Is it a file?

The texture is a square image, and it's 5 x 3 tiles. I've just used an Object texture coordinate and the correct face attributes option to repeat it. I'm wondering how to overlay a grid that has the same size tiles, but has differently oriented gradients in each.

You can probably adjust the input values here to match your texture.

Where:

Offset_X and Offset_Y: values that you adjust to slide the gradient tiles
Tiles_X and Tiles_Y: values that you adjust to control de number of gradient tiles in each direction (in UV for a plane, this number matches exactly, in "Object", the result seem to be doubled, you will need to find what is optimal for your case)

Explanation:

Using "snap" in the vector creates constant regions without variation in coordinates. Each constant reagion is a tile
When you feed snapped vectors to the noise texture, it samples a constant noise for each tile
In parallel, we scale and repeat the vectors for creting gradients. The floored module tells how far from a step value the coordinate is.
An additional mapping with (location = 0.25 and scale = 0.5) is used so the gradient doesn't reach its limits (0 and 1). It gets constant on the limits and we don't want that.
We then use the constant noise values to rotate the tiled vector and input to the gradient texture

